# NodeJs + ExpressJs app routing odd behavior

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am learning ExpressJS. So far I have setup a simple todo app with user authentication using PassportJS. I use Mongoose for repository. There is nothing in the web to explain the odd behavior that I'm seeing with my route setup.

Scenario:

- When I hit get /passport it will direct to the passport page
  (login/signup)
- When I hit get /aslkdjf it will direct to the passport    page if
  user is not logged in, else it will direct to the file
  /public/index.html)
- When I hit get / it should direct to the    passport    page if user
  is not logged in, but it goes to    /public/index.html    instead and
  my todo app would fail as req.user.username under /api/todos is
  undefiend

Strangely, when I remove the router.get('/*', ... configuration, my app would still go to public/index.html, when I hit base path '/', but not when I hit '/asdfa'.

```js
    ...
    
    function loggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.user) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/passport');
        }
    }

    var router = express.Router();
// passport ----------------------------------------------------------------
// get passport page
router.get('/passport', notLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/passport.html');
});

// post login
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/passport',
    failureFlash: true
}));

// post registration
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/passport',
    failureFlash: true
}));

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

// api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// get all todos
router.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
    Todo.find({owner: req.user.username}, function(err, todos) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(todos); // return all todos in JSON format
    });
});

// create todo and send back all todos after creation
router.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        owner: req.user.username,
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find({owner: req.user.username}, function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});

// delete a todo
router.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find({owner: req.user.username}, function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
router.all('*', loggedIn);
router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

    app.use('/', router);
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("App listening on port 3000");
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on? All I want to achieve is to make the app re-route user to the login page when they are not logged in and they go to www.myapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem is that HTML defaults to finding an index.html file in any folder within the root. When I change the html file to something else like abc.html the problem is solved. Seems like a bug to me.